# How to resize an image's byte[] while keeping proportions?

Tags: c#, arrays, image, asp.net-mvc-4, thumbnails

In my ASP.Net MVC 4 application, I have a View that allows users to hover over an image to get a full-sized preview. It works well.

Currently, I have the image that the user hovers over set to a static width and height of 50 and 50, like so:

```
<img id="@Model.Value" class="image-preview" height="50" width="50" src="@Model.ImageString" />
```

`@Model.ImageString` is a value that gets created by this Action:

```
[HttpGet]
public string GetImageUrl(Guid fileId)
{
    var file = db.FetchedFiles
        .First(ff => ff.ID == fileId);

    return "data:image/*;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(file.Data);
}
```

The above Action is what I'd like to modify. How can I output the `Convert.ToBase64String(file.Data)` as a thumbnail image with the same proportions as the original file?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I found inspiration somewhere on the web and ended up with this:

```
string ResizeImage(byte[] data)
{
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream(data))
    {
        var image = Image.FromStream(ms);

        var ratioX = (double)150 / image.Width;
        var ratioY = (double)50 / image.Height;

        var ratio = Math.Min(ratioX, ratioY);

        var width = (int)(image.Width * ratio);
        var height = (int)(image.Height * ratio);

        var newImage = new Bitmap(width, height);

        Graphics.FromImage(newImage).DrawImage(image, 0, 0, width, height);

        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(newImage);

        ImageConverter converter = new ImageConverter();

        data = (byte[])converter.ConvertTo(bmp, typeof(byte[]));

        return "data:image/*;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(data);
    }
}
```

Comment: Where does ImageConverter comes from? I don't find it it System.Drawing

Comment: @Anuj Sorry for the late reply, but this is the best resource I can provide. If the type doesn't exist in that namespace, you probably have a reference related issue in your environment. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.imageconverter?view=netframework-4.8

Answer (score 0):

You will need to return a new image that has been resized on the server.

By far, the easiest way would be to use [ImageResizing](http://imageresizing.net/) and simply pass in the file stream along with the `ResizeSettings` to specify the dimensions you want. Then simply return the resized file as `base64`.

The library is very extensive, and well documented with plenty of examples, so you should be able to find a solution or adapt one to fit your needs.

Here is one example: http://imageresizing.net/docs/howto/upload-and-resize